# Right click on one email in outlook and export specific data to a template

Tags: windows, email, outlook, crm

So here i am going through multiple spam mail till i find a email that i have to make a note of to do something with and thought wouldn't it be nice if i could right click in Outlook 2010  email and export the data to a file i.e creating a job in a CRM system. Have had a search in Google and wasn't impressed with my results and wonder if anyone had any thoughts or ideas? I'm assuming such programs doesn't already exist and so any programming thoughts would be good to accomplish?

Now I'm not looking for a program that does multiple emails from a folder but an email that i have selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program doesn't exist - you would need to create an [Outlook Add-in using VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx) to perform this task.

It would be trivial to implement - just latch on to [`ThisAddin.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861267.aspx) and cast the selection to a [`MailItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332.aspx). From there, you can access all message properties (*subject, recipients, body, etc.*).